# Common reasons for high memory consumption in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

My jenkins is utilizing 41GB of virtual memory for jobs/builds on production server, that is too much.
**what are reasons that why my jenkins is utilizing too much memory???**. I'm having 40-50 slaves and everyday total 50-70 jobs are triggered. also is there any solution to tackle this memory issues in Jenkins

Comment: what jenkins version are you using?

Comment: using 2.150.1 version on linux machine

Comment: can you further explain your jenkins infrastructure? jenkins master specs, slaves specs, how many executors on each, etc?